# Why does malloc_trim() only work with the main arena?

Tags: c++, c, glibc

glibc's malloc implementation supports 'malloc_trim()' call that lets an application program release unused(ie freed memory chunks) back to the system(implementation detail: the data segment of the program is reduced by calling sbrk() with a negative argument). However, this function only works with the main arena. In multithreaded programs, there are multiple arenas that hold freed chunks. Why does this call not release memory from the other arenas as well?

Comment: possibly because it's not a good idea to free memory from a different arena than it was allocated ... it can only free memory from the top of the heap as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arenas other than the main one are probably allocated from the system using `mmap` so `sbrk` cannot be used to return that memory to the system. It could be possible to make glibc use `mremap` to shrink these other arenas. Note also that `malloc_trim` can only return memory at the end of the arena, if there are empty blocks in the middle of the arena there's no way to release that memory.

Comment: Geoff, thanks for the reply. I am researching this in glibc code, and will update this question with an answer about what I find.

Comment: Geoff, thanks, your answer is correct. 'sbrk' can be used to shrink only the data segment of the program, and hence malloc_trim only works with the main arena which is located there.